# java.lang.Byte symbol not found

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]My program was running fine last time I ran it. I opened it today and now it is saying

```
symbol class Byte symbol not found for import java.lang.Byte;
```

I don't know where to look to troubleshoot this problem. I **re-installed java**.

I am running this on Netbeans on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

I added an image showing that java.lang.Byte exists in my projects library but it gives me an error. It compiled with javac so I think its my netbeans setup. Also I can refer to java.lang.Boolean (two classes above my Byte class. Any more clues you guys can give?

Comment: Do you get an error during compilation, or only when running? Have you tried compiling manually using javac to see if the same thing happens?

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your java/IDE setup, java.lang.Byte is part of standard library, so should always be there. Check what is on the classpath and make sure you have the JAVA_HOME specified and java installed.

Comment: In NetBeans, a good place to start would be opening the Tools menu, then choose Java Platforms and check what's available and what's the default. Make sure your project setup uses an available version.

Comment: I have a JRE folder and a JDK folder. And my CLASSPATH is ".;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip"
My JAVA_HOME is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23"
And in my netbeans project I can find java.lang.Byte. Still getting the error

Comment: try compiling your code outside of the netbeans using javac. This way you can see if there are problems with JRE/JDK.

Comment: okay it compiled with javac but when I ran it I get classNotFoundException. I never ran java in a command prompt so I don't know if there is a problem running a netbeans project in the command prompt. I made a hello world project which runs in netbeans but I get the same error in command prompt if that helps.

Comment: Most likely you are running from the wrong directory. If you class has the package com.aaa.bbb you need to run it from the directory above com, not from where the class is located.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you do not need to import anything that's in the `java.lang` package. The content of the `java.lang` package is always available automatically. Remove the `import` line from your source file.

Importing something from `java.lang` does not normally lead to an error message, however. Something must be wrong with your Java setup if you get an error like you say you do.